# Let $f(x) = \lfloor x \lfloor x \rfloor \rfloor$ for $x \ge 0.$

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions

(a) Find all $x \ge 0$ such that $f(x) = 1.$
(b) Find all $x \ge 0$ such that $f(x) = 3.$
(c) Find all $x \ge 0$ such that $f(x) = 5.$
(d) Find the number of possible values of $f(x)$ for $0 \le x \le 10.$

I don't exactly know how I can attempt to do this. First I said (for part a) that $1\leq x \cdot \lfloor{x} \rfloor <2$ then divided by $x$ and split the remaining floor function into $x-[x]$, where $[x]$ is the fractional part of $x$. Simplified a few things out and now I have $\frac{x-1}{x} \geq [x] > \frac{x-2}{x}$.

Not sure how to proceed from here or if I'm even working in the right direction. I think if I can get help for part $a$ then I may be able to do the rest on my own?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you say, you want $1\le x\lfloor x\rfloor<2$. It’s easy to check that $x\lfloor x\rfloor\ge 2$ if $x\ge 2$, so you can assume that $x<2$. Similarly, it’s clear that $x\lfloor x\rfloor<1$ if $x<1$, so you can assume that $x\ge 1$. And if $1\le x<2$, then $\lfloor x\rfloor=1$, so $x\lfloor x\rfloor=x$, and $f(x)=1$.

Note that $f$ is a non-decreasing function, $f(2)=4$, and $f(3)=9$, so if $f(x)=5$, then $2<x<3$. To find the actual interval, we want to solve $x_0\lfloor x_0\rfloor=5$ and $x_1\lfloor x_1\rfloor=6$ for $x_0$ and $x_1$. We know that $\lfloor x_0\rfloor=\lfloor x_1\rfloor=2$, so the first is easy: $x_0=\frac52$. The second has no solution, but $x\lfloor x\rfloor<6$ for $x<3$, so $f(x)=5$ if and only if $\frac52\le x<3$.

I’ll leave the rest to you.

Comment: So f(x) = 1 when 1 ≤ x < 2, and f(x) = 5 when 5/2 ≤ x < 3? How do you find all x for f(x) = 3 and the number of values of f(x) for 0 ≤ x ≤ 10?

Comment: @RobertMugabe: What I did in that answer is already enough to tell you what solutions $f(x)=3$ has: $f(x)=1$ for $1\le x<2$, and $f(2)=4$, so there are obviously no values of $x$ for which $f(x)=3$. Now use the same techniques to find what values $f(x)$ has between $f(2)=4$ and $f(3)=9$, between $f(3)=9$ and $f(4)=16$, and so on, up to $f(10)=100$.

Comment: Wouldn't there just be 11 possible values of f(x) for 0 ≤ x ≤ 10 since there are 11 numbers...

Comment: @RobertMugabe: No. $f(x)$ takes only one value on the interval $[0,1)$ and on the interval $[1,2)$, but we've seen that it takes two values on the interval $[2,3)$, for instance. Using similar ideas, you should be able to work out that it takes three different values on the interval $[3,4)$.